# Ubuntu freezes during installation

Tags: installation

Good morning people,

I have a laptop in which I installed Ubuntu and CentOS without problems some time ago. However, today I am trying to install Ubuntu in my Desktop computer but it is not possible. The installation freezes, the LiveCD cannot execute.

I've been investigating and I noticed that the installation and LiveCD freeze when executing `irqbalance`. Do you have any ideas in order for me to install Linux in my Desktop computer?

My Desktop computer is:

- AMD Athlon 64 3200+ 2000MHZ
- 2,5GB RAM
- ATI Radeon X1650XT 256

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Centos on the laptop you will need to remove it in order to install Ubuntu.

To do this you can either:

Load your BIOS and sanitize your HDD

Or either install GPARTED Live to a USB and delete the Cent OS partitions

Comment: I have problems with my Desktop computer. I had CentOS in my Laptop, but is is not the problem.

Comment: Did you recently install Ubuntu and removed the USB or canceled the installation?

Comment: No, I never tried to install linux in that PC.